# Cloud Page Unsubscribe functionality not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, cloudpage

We have 2 cloud pages. Our requirement is the global opt-out for emails. So when someone clicks on unsubscribe on the first page they should get unsubscribed from MC and Salesforce CRM. The rendering is working fine but the functionality of updating All subs / CRM is not working.

**Code on Page 1  :**

```
%%[
set @subkey = RequestParameter("subscriberkey")
set @email = RequestParameter("Emailaddress")

if Not Empty(@subkey) then
set @statusrows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("contact","EMailOptout","ContactId", "=", @subkey)
    if RowCount(@statusrows) > 0 then
        set @statusrow = Row(@statusrows, 1)
        set @Unsubscribe = FIELD(@statusrow,"PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail")      
endif
endif


  
  <div class="container">
    <p class="container__copy">
 we’ll remove your address, <br><strong>%%=v(@email)=%%</strong>, from our mailing list.
    </p>
 <form name="form" action="https://" method="post">
<div style="font-size: 18px; margin: 8px 0px 0px 20px;" align="center">
<input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true">
<input name="subkey" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@subkey)=%%">
<input name="email" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@email)=%%">
<br>
<input class="container__button" type="submit" value="Unsubscribe">
```

Code on Page 2

```
%%[set @subkey = RequestParameter("subkey") 

set @email = RequestParameter("email") 


if RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN 
   
        
         
       SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact", @subkey,
       "EmailOptout", "true")
       
          /* update Preference Page DE in Marketing Cloud */
          
    SET @updatePrefDE = UpsertData('MasterPreferences_DEV',1,'SubscriberKey',@subkey, 'unsubscribed',"True")
  
    
 
 /* log unsubscribe event to mark as unsubscribed in All Subscribers */
SET @reason = "Unsubscribed through custom preference center"

SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SETObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

endif
]%%
```

I have used Cloudpage URL function and passing subscriber key,email address parameters on the email footer where someone can click unsubscribe

Comment: Please share MORE DETAILS on ERROR which you are getting, which helps community to better understand the issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue